# Going from $\sqrt A = \sqrt A$ to $\sqrt A= \sqrt{A\cdot(-1)^2}$ to $\sqrt A = -\sqrt A$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Assume A is a positive real number. If 
$$\sqrt A = \sqrt A,$$
then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt A &= \sqrt{A\cdot(-1)^2}\\
\text{or},\ \ \ \sqrt A &= -\sqrt A.
\end{aligned}
$$
How does this work?

Comment: Clarification: (Assuming the variable A is a positive real number) if the square root of A equals the square root of A, then the square root of A equals the square root of A equals the square root of A times negative one raised to 2. Then, this proves the square root of A equals the negative square root of A.

Comment: $\sqrt{(-1)^2} = 1$ and not $-1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Squaring is not injective. From $a^2 = b^2$, you cannot conclude $a = b$

Answer (score 2):

For real positive numbers, the squareroot is defined as $$\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$$ that is, always positive. If we defined it as $$\sqrt{a^2}=a$$ we would get a problem, namely $$\sqrt{1}=\sqrt{(-1)^2}\Rightarrow 1=-1$$ This problem arises because $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$, $f(x)=x^2$ is not injective, that is, $x^2=y^2$ does not imply $x=y$.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is that you are trying to conclude $\sqrt{A}=-\sqrt{A}$ from $A=A\cdot(-1)^2$. While one can simply note that squaring is non-injective as a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, we can also give a simpler argument with less mathematical jargon involved. We can argue as follows.

$A=A\cdot(-1)^2$

$\implies (\sqrt{A})^2=(-\sqrt{A})^2$

$\implies (\sqrt{A})^2-(-\sqrt{A})^2=0$

$\implies (\sqrt{A}-\sqrt{A})(\sqrt{A}+\sqrt{A})=0$

$\implies 0(\sqrt{A}+\sqrt{A})=0$

which is a mathematical identity for real numbers. So there is no clash!